# Unhandled Exception: System.IO.Exception: Critical file stream blocked

Tags: c#

so a person that is using my software gets an error when they launch the app:

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Critical file stream blocked.
at Installer.Program.Main(String[] args)
Press any key to continue . . .

Does anyone know how to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: The mention of "installer" makes me wonder whether this is a permissions thing; is the account elevated?

Comment: @MarcGravell No, it's the software's name.

Comment: So the application dies right at the beginning of execution? Sounds like a perms issue, as @MarcGravell said. It seems stdin/stdout are blocked for some reason

Comment: We need a better translation of the error message, do post the original text.  Smells like anti-malware getting in the way btw.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.